# Xquery performance in order to return top levels

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, xquery

I have a large XML file and I use bulk load for taking it. The sample of my file is like this:

```
<Root Parts="Mypart">  
.
.
<part number="100000">  
<PT pt1="1" pt2="2" ... pt5="5"/>
.
.
<PT pt6="6" pt7="7" ... pt9="9"/>
</part>
.
.
</Root>
```

Because I need to save attributes of parts and also numbers of them I use "**../../**" to fetch numbers of parts and my output in SQL table likes below:

```
100000 1 2 3 4 5
.
.
100000 6 7 8 9
```

but its performance is not good. 
Is there any way to increase it?
Thanks.

EDIT: According to your comment below your current query is

```
select t.n.value('(../../@number)[1]','nvarchar(100)') num 
      ,t.n.value('(.//@pt1[1]','nvarchar(10)')) A1 
      ,t.n.value('(.//@pt2[1]','nvarchar(10)')) A2 
      ,t.n.value('(.//@pt1[3]','nvarchar(10)')) A3 
FROM @XmlFile.nodes('Root/Parts[sql:variable("@cnt")]/part/pt') AS t(n)
```

Comment: Can you share your XQuery? Have you tried excluding the references to `../../@number` to prove that is where your performance issue is, or that it is having a significant impact? Have you tried assigning the referenced `../../@number` to a variable?

Comment: Mads Hansen - yes, exactly I have tried assigning  ../../@number to variable but just because of it, performance is low.

Comment: and if you have no reference to `@number` (i.e. hard-code a value) it runs noticeable faster?

Comment: I ran an XQuery to generate sample content with 5,000 `<PT>` elements and return the example outputs and saw no discernible difference between hard-coded values, variable reference with nested for loops, or referencing the parent element. Each took about 5 seconds. Show your XQuery and let us know what processor you are using.

Comment: my query is: select t.n.value('(../../@number)[1]','nvarchar(100)') num
   ,t.n.value('(.//@pt1[1]','nvarchar(10)')) A1
    ,t.n.value('(.//@pt2[1]','nvarchar(10)')) A2  ,t.n.value('(.//@pt1[3]','nvarchar(10)')) A3   FROM @XmlFile.nodes('Root/Parts[sql:variable("@cnt")]/part/pt') AS t(n)

Comment: Performance depends on the XQuery implementation you are using. No-one can answer a performance question without knowing the specific product.

Comment: Hi @SMD, I just edited my answer and added some hints about XPath filters...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a lot of expensive and absolutely unneeded XPath-walk-arounds. Try it like this:

```
DECLARE @XmlFile XML=
'<Root Parts="Mypart">  
<part number="100000">  
<PT pt1="1" pt2="2"  pt5="5"/>
<PT pt6="6" pt7="7" pt9="9"/>
</part>
<part number="20000">  
<PT pt1="1" pt2="2"  pt5="5"/>
<PT pt6="6" pt7="7" pt9="9"/>
</part>
</Root>';

select @XmlFile.value('/Root[1]/@Mypart','nvarchar(max)') AS MyPart
      ,Part.value('@number','nvarchar(100)') num --might be numeric...
      ,PT.value('@pt1','nvarchar(10)') A1 
      ,PT.value('@pt2','nvarchar(10)') A2 
      ,PT.value('@pt5','nvarchar(10)') A5 
      ,PT.value('@pt6','nvarchar(10)') A6
      ,PT.value('@pt7','nvarchar(10)') A7 
      ,PT.value('@pt9','nvarchar(10)') A9 
FROM @XmlFile.nodes('Root/part') AS One(Part)
CROSS APPLY Part.nodes('PT') AS The(PT)
```

Then there is this `@cnt` variable. This will limit the output to the n^th element... You set this on the n^th element of "Parts", but your example has only a "Parts" attribut... You don't show the full XML, but there's something wrong I suppose... Are you traversing this XML in a loop? This would slow down the whole process...

Some hints about XPath filters:

```
DECLARE @xml XML='<root> 
                  <a filter="hallo" test="100"/>
                  <a filter="" test="200"/>
                  <a test="300"/>
                  <a test="400"/>
                  <a test="500"/>
                  </root>';
SELECT a.value('@test','int') AS test FROM @xml.nodes('/root/a[3]') AS One(a);
--Just "300" -> the third element
SELECT a.value('@test','int') AS test FROM @xml.nodes('/root/a[@test=3]') AS One(a);
--nothing
SELECT a.value('@test','int') AS test FROM @xml.nodes('/root/a[@filter="hallo"]') AS One(a);
--"100", due to filter=hallo
```

If you really want to read one special part only (as by your query mentioned in comment), you might add a filter like this:

```
FROM @XmlFile.nodes('Root/part[@number=sql:variable("@cnt")]') AS One(Part)
```

Comment: Hi @Shnugo, You are right and I traversed my XML in wrong loops and because of this mistake whole of process slowed down. Your answer is fast and doesn't have unnecessary traverses. Thanks a lot